# In Django test there is empty queryset when assigned to variable but not empty when printed in console during debug

Tags: python, django, django-models, automated-tests, django-testing

I'm debugging **Django (1.11.8)** test and observing strange behavior, when stopped in debugger and switched to `Ipython` console typing:

```
Model.objects.all()
```

returns non-empty `Queryset`. However, when the same expressions is assigned to variable e.g.:

```
obj_qs = Model.objects.all()
```

then `obj_qs` is empty Queryset. I would expect the same result from both statements. Am I missing something important in tests setup? I'm using both `setUpTestData()` and `setUp()` methods to initialize objects for the test.

Comment: have you creating new entries to Model in SetUp ?

Comment: Objects in Model are created in setUpTestData() of another mixin class and these objects are not modified in setUp() of the test I'm running.

Comment: usually when tests run it will create a test database and we have to create some sample test data in SetUp class, It won't test the data previously in database, So can you mention your tests also ?

Answer (score 0):

The short explanation of this effect is that **Querysets are lazy**. I was checking `Queryset` before it was evaluated in the code that is why during debugging empty queryset was observed - making few steps forward to the lines where `Queryset` was actually used, proved that everything is OK.